# Как определить первую запись в цикле foreach

Tags: php, циклы, foreach

есть массив, после прохождения по массиву циклом foreach нужно определить первую запись
к примеру:

```
foreach ($nav as $item) {

}
```

Прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста пример, для чего вам это понадобилось

Comment: а чем не устроило обращение к первому элементу массива `$nav[0]`?

Comment: @Эдуард Не знаю чего добивается автор вопроса, но такой элемент может оказаться совсем не первым

Comment: @tutankhamun ну если так, то я добавил свой вариант ответа.

Answer (score 4):

Надо использовать другой вид foreach:

```
$keys = array_keys( $nav );
foreach ($nav as $key => $item) {
     if ( $keys[0] === $key) {
         // это первая запись
    }
}
```

Comment: А если массив ассоциативный? :]

Comment: А по хорошему они все ассоциативные, просто некоторые ведут себя как списки. Может даже быть такая дичь `$a = array(1 => 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 0 => 100, 6 => 106);`

Comment: @Manitikyl подправил под любой вид массива.

Answer (score 1):

```
$first = TRUE;
foreach ($ARRAY as $item) {
    if ($first == TRUE) {
        // первый
        $first = FALSE;
    }
}
```

И еще вариант:

```
reset($ARRAY);
$first = key($ARRAY);
foreach($ARRAY as $key => $item) {
    if ($key === $first) {
        // первый
    }
}
```

На самом деле варианты можно всю вечность накидывать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто запустить цикл ровно на одну итерацию, и прервать его выполнение. После этого в переменной `$item` будет сохранён первый элемент:

```
$array = ['key' => 'Первый элемент', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

foreach ($array as $item) break;
echo $item;
```

Но можно обойтись и без цикла:

```
echo array_shift($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

foreach в php не имеет счётчика итераций, поэтому придётся посчитать самим. Это совсем не сложно:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    if ($i === 0) {
        // первая итерация
    }

    ++$i;
}
```

Удивительно, но этот же метод позволит определить последнюю итерацию и какую-нибудь кратную итерацию!

```
$i = 0;
$lastPos = count($arr) - 1;
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    if ($i === 0) {
        // первая итерация
    }

    if ($i === $lastPos) {
        // последняя итерация
    }

    if ($i % 2) {
        // каждая чётная итерация
    }

    ++$i;
}
```

Если вам нужно просто первый элемент массива получить без обхода массива, используйте [reset](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.reset.php).